# wrong sequence number using tun/tap interface

Tags: c++, c, tcp, tshark, tun-tap

I'm trying to read TCP packets into a struct using tun/tap,
So IFF_TUN flag is set to use tun device (no ethernet headers).

I have structs like these (I don't care about endian issues):

Tcp Header:

```
struct tcphdr {
  uint16_t sport;
  uint16_t dport;
  uint32_t seq;
  uint32_t ack_seq;
  uint8_t rsvd : 4;
  uint8_t dataoff : 4;
  uint8_t fin : 1,
          syn : 1,
          rst : 1,
          psh : 1,
          ack : 1,
          urg : 1,
          ece : 1,
          cwr : 1;
  uint16_t win;
  uint16_t csum;
  uint16_t urp;
} __attribute__((packed));
```

Ipv4 Header:

```
struct ipv4hdr {
  uint8_t ihl : 4;
  uint8_t version : 4;
  uint8_t tos;
  uint16_t len;
  uint16_t id;
  uint16_t frag_offset;
  uint8_t ttl;
  uint8_t proto;
  uint16_t csum;
  uint32_t saddr;
  uint32_t daddr;
} __attribute__((packed));
```

and read packets like this:

```
size_t nbytes = read(fd, bytes, 1504); // fd is eg. fd = open("/dev/net/tun", O_RDWR)

uint16_t eth_flags = bytes[0] << 8 | bytes[1]; // big-endian
uint16_t eth_proto = bytes[2] << 8 | bytes[3]; // big-endian

if (eth_proto != 0x800)
  // ignore no ipv4 packets
  // https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EtherType
  continue;

if (ip_hdr->proto != 0x06)
  // ignore non-TCP packets
  // https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_IP_protocol_numbers
  continue;
```

and so far, so good. but when i try to read the TCP sequece number i get wrong number:

```
ipv4hdr *ip_hdr = (ipv4hdr *)(bytes + 4); // 4 first bytes are packet information provided by kernel
tcphdr *tcp_hdr = (tcphdr *)(bytes + 4 + ip_hdr->ihl * 4); // reading TCP at the end of the IP header
std::cout << std::hex << ntohl(tcp_hdr->seq) << std::endl; // the output number is wrong!
```

tshark output shows seq=0 (like below):

```
Capturing on 'tun0'
    1 0.000000000  192.168.0.1 → 192.168.0.2  TCP 60 44248 → 8000 [SYN] Seq=0 Win=29200 Len=0 MSS=1460 SACK_PERM=1 TSval=1233752815 TSecr=0 WS=128
```

but my code output is **7be53b39**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some search i found the solution.

refer to [wireshark wiki](https://wiki.wireshark.org/TCP_Relative_Sequence_Numbers):

> By default Wireshark and TShark will keep track of all TCP sessions
>   and convert all Sequence Numbers (SEQ numbers) and Acknowledge Numbers
>   (ACK Numbers) into relative numbers. This means that instead of
>   displaying the real/absolute SEQ and ACK numbers in the display,
>   Wireshark will display a SEQ and ACK number relative to the first seen
>   segment for that conversation.

all sequence numbers always start at 0 for the first packet seen in each conversation, so my output wasn't wrong :)